# Coldfusion date difference in days and hours

Tags: date, coldfusion, datediff

I'm having a problem with Coldfusion's DateDiff(). I'm trying to get the difference between two dates with times, like the following examples:

```
fromdate=06/11/2017 22:10
todate  =16/11/2017 23:20
```

should return:

> 10 days, 1 hour and 10 minutes

```
fromdate=06/11/2017 22:10
todate  =16/11/2017 20:20
```

should return:

> 9 days, 22 hours, 10 minutes

Any help?

**Code:**

```
<cfset dtFrom = "11/06/2017 22:10" /> 
<cfset dtTo = "11/16/2017 23:20" />

<cfoutput>
#DateDiff( "d", dtFrom, dtTo)# Days, 
#DateDiff( "h", dtFrom, dtTo) % 24# Hours 
#DateDiff( "n", dtFrom, dtTo) % 24 % 60# Minutes 
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is it returning? Also add the source in code blocks so we can see what you do

Comment: `code
<cfset dtFrom = "11/06/2017 22:10" />
<cfset dtTo = "11/16/2017 23:20" />
#DateDiff( "d", dtFrom, dtTo)# Days,
#DateDiff( "h", dtFrom, dtTo) % 24# Hours
#DateDiff( "n", dtFrom, dtTo) % 24 % 60# Minutes
`
returns:  10 Days, 1 Hours 22 Minutes
`code
<cfset dtFrom = "11/06/2017 22:10" />
<cfset dtTo = "11/16/2017 21:20" />`
returns: 9 Days, 23 Hours 22 Minutes

Comment: Can you edit that into your post? Doesnt it work already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
totalMinutes = datediff("n", fromDate, toDate);
days = int(totalMinutes /(24 * 60)) ;
minutesRemaining = totalMinutes - (days * 24 * 60);
hours = int(minutesRemaining / 60);
minutes = minutesRemaining mod 60;
writeoutput(days & ' days ' & hours & ' hours ' & minutes & ' minutes');
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [the previous suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47137750), `DateDiff()` isn't going to understand those **specific** strings or that "06/11/2017" should mean November 6. The result will be:

```
158 days 1 hours 10 minutes
```

For it to work as expected, you must convert the strings into date objects first. For example use [LSParseDateTime](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/lsparsedatetime.html) with the right Locale.

```
fromDate = lsParseDateTime("06/11/2017 22:10", "English (UK)", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
toDate = lsParseDateTime("16/11/2017 23:20", "English (UK)", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
```

or possibly:

```
fromDate = lsParseDateTime("06/11/2017 22:10", "English (UK)");
toDate = lsParseDateTime("16/11/2017 23:20", "English (UK)");
```